# ImageMagick: How to compare original PNG to lossy JPEG?

Tags: java, image-processing, imagemagick

I want to compare original PNG image to lossy JPEG image to see how much I am loosing. I found that I can use ImageMagic to compare images. I prefer using Java (im4java). I am very confused with their documentation (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php). It doesn't describe which platform it is for. How do I use these command lines and are they even available in im4java? If someone can write steps on how I use it I will appreciate it.

Comment: Note though.. Although this kind of tool can help you find differences, and even if you break it into a PSNR delta... there is nothing that can model human perception.  Whether or not the loss is objectionable is ultimately a question for human eyes.  Take, for example, audio compression (yes... this is audio perception).  This generally works by throwing out the midrange... but it is generally not noticeable.  If you take the highs and throw away half as much data.... it will still be more objectionable/noticeable throwing out the mids.

Comment: @John Green, that is poor description of perceptual audio coding.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - You're probably right.  My forays into writing were met with limited success.  : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick runs on many platforms. If you click [Binary Releases](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), they have a listing of available packages. The `im4java` library, as its home page describes, calls the ImageMagick command line tools to do its work, so it will run on any platform that supports both ImageMagick and Java. Browsing through its [API documentation](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/api/), it looks like the `compare` command is not available in im4java, so you must modify im4java to support it.

Comment: In that case is there any other library that has it ? I just want to compare performance of jpg converter .Just one time deal.

Comment: Ended up using Windows solution in ImageMagic.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So why can't you use the ImageMagick commandline tool directly?

Note, that comparing 2 different images with the help of `compare` only leads to meaningfull results if the two do have the same dimensions (Width x Height) in terms of pixels. `compare` does a comparison that is done pixel by pixel.

Here's how I would do it:

```
 compare \
       -verbose \
       -debug coder \
       -log "%u %m:%l %e" \
        orig1.png \
        orig2.jpeg \
       -compose src \
        diff.png
```

This command takes 2 images as input: `orig1.png` and `orig2.jpeg`. It produces `diff.png` as output. It also gives you some debugging info on *stdout*. The output image has all pixels colored in red which are different between the inputs.

Another possibility is this modified command:

```
 compare \
       -verbose \
       -debug coder \
       -log "%u %m:%l %e" \
        orig1.png \
        orig2.jpeg \
       -compose difference \
        diff.png
```

It visualizes the differences in another way. You could also not write the differences to a file, but tell compare to open a window and display the differences on screen:

```
 compare \
       -verbose \
       -debug coder \
       -log "%u %m:%l %e" \
        orig1.png \
        orig2.jpeg \
       -compose difference \
        x:
```

Answer (score 0):

My blog entry is more about [JPEG quality and what is the difference of ImageMagick and Lightroom](http://www.drillio.com/en/photography/image-quality/best-jpg-quality-imagemagick-vs-lightroom/), but you can find the helpful command line that does the required comparison:

```
composite image1.ext image2.ext -compose difference diff.png
```

Ensure that you use .png (or .gif or other lossless format) as the output image, because first of all you are interested in the difference, and .jpg would distort it as a photo.